# Web API 2 Ninject "error occurred when trying to create a controller"

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I'm getting this error when loading my controller.

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MembersController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

I have added

```
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver.NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel);
```

to the `NinjectWebCommon` class after registering the bindings.

And I have registered the relevant services. see ***EDIT***

```
 private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
 {
     kernel.Bind<IMembersService, MembersService>();
     kernel.Bind<MemberContext, MemberContext>();
 }
```

Here are the ninject packages I have added -

```
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.MVC5" version="3.2.1.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.0.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net451" />
  <package id="Ninject.WebApi.DependencyResolver" version="0.1.4758.24814" targetFramework="net451" />
```

What am I missing?

***EDIT***

Thanks to my conversation with Jerrod Horton (below) I realized I doing the binding incorrectly.

Should have been

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{
    kernel.Bind<IMembersService>().To<MembersService>();
    kernel.Bind<MemberContext>().To<MemberContext>();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your dependencies (or a dependency of a dependency) is not fully registered with the IoC container.  When web api attempts to resolve the controller if it does not have every single dependency it needs then it will fail and If your IoC container is trying to resolve ProductRepository but ProductRepository requires in its constructor ISqlConnectionProvider then you must register ISqlConnectionProvider with your IoC container as well.

I would start at the controller.  Look at all input parameters.  Make sure each are registered with your IoC container.  Then go through each of those classes and make sure any dependencies within those are registered as well (and so on and so forth).

Here is the code that I have that works for Ninject.  This code exists in the App_Start folder in a file called NinjectWebCommon.cs

```
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(YourProject.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Start")]
[assembly: WebActivatorEx.ApplicationShutdownMethodAttribute(typeof(YourProject.App_Start.NinjectWebCommon), "Stop")]

namespace YourProject.App_Start
{
    using System;
    using System.Web;

    using Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.DynamicModuleHelper;

    using Ninject;
    using Ninject.Web.Common;

    public static class NinjectWebCommon 
    {
        private static readonly Bootstrapper bootstrapper = new Bootstrapper();

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the application
        /// </summary>
        public static void Start() 
        {
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(OnePerRequestHttpModule));
            DynamicModuleUtility.RegisterModule(typeof(NinjectHttpModule));
            bootstrapper.Initialize(CreateKernel);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the application.
        /// </summary>
        public static void Stop()
        {
            bootstrapper.ShutDown();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Creates the kernel that will manage your application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The created kernel.</returns>
        private static IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            try
            {
                kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
                kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

                RegisterServices(kernel);
                return kernel;
            }
            catch
            {
                kernel.Dispose();
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Load your modules or register your services here!
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="kernel">The kernel.</param>
        private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
        {
        }        
    }
}
```

packages.config Ninject snippet

```
  <package id="Ninject" version="3.2.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.Common.WebHost" version="3.2.3.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

packages.config web api and asp.net snippet

```
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.HelpPage" version="5.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.0" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net45" />
```

Comment: I have all two dependencies.

Comment: I edited my response to include the code that is working for me.  Hopefully this helps you out.  The ""RegisterServices" method is the method I register my dependencies.

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using web api 2?

Comment: We are 100% using web api 2.  I have updated the response with the snippet from the packages.config for ninject.

Comment: With your code --- return resolver.TryGet(serviceType); ---- I'm getting  'System.NullReferenceException'... I remember ninject being easy to work with, what has happened?

Comment: It seems to work for me, no problem.  I remember having a similar issue that you were having.  Once it is set up it works perfectly.  If it is not set up JUST right, you have frustrating issues like the one you are having.  If you copy and paste this code that I have into your code it should work.  Make sure that you have the MVC Ninject nuget package installed (it looks like you do).

Comment: Do you have '<package id="Ninject.Web.WebApi" version="3.2.4.0" targetFramework="net451" />' ? Could you paste in all the ninject packages in your packages.config?

Comment: I pasted all of the Ninject ones that I had (word for word) at the bottom of my response so you could see them.  I'll go ahead and post up the web api ones too just in case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101624/discussion-between-bryan-and-jerrod-horton).

Answer (score 5):

Short answer:

You need to have all of these packages installed:

- Ninject
- Ninject.Extensions.Conventions
- Ninject.Web.Common
- Ninject.Web.Mvc
- Ninject.Web.WebApi
- Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost

Missing one of these is causing the problem in most situations.

Comment: Had a joint MVC and WebAPI project - was missing Ninject.Web.WebApi in the new project, but gave me this baffling error instead of something more reasonable